# double dash before a variable in C++

Tags: c++, operators

Sorry if this is a beginner question, but I could not find an answer anywhere - I came across a class destructor in C++, in which there is

```
--num_strings;
```

I am wondering what the double dash means. Any help is appreciated, thanks. Below are parts of the header and cpp files:

```
// strngbad.h
#include <iostream>
class StringBad
{
private: 
    char * str;
    int len;
    static int num_strings;

public:
    StringBad(const char * s);
    StringBad();
    ~StringBad();
};
```

---

```
//  strngbad.cpp
#include <cstring>
#include "strngbad.h"
using std::cout;
....
....
....

StringBad::StringBad(const char *s)
{
    len = std::strlen(s);
    str = new char[len + 1];
    std::strcpy(str, s);
    num_strings++;
}

StringBad::~StringBad()
{
    --num_strings;
    delete [] str;
}
```

Comment: Why do you know what a class and destructor is, but you don't even know the arithmetic operators yet? What source are you learning C++ from?

Comment: Search for [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B). Why don't read a C++ book first?

Comment: @JerryHu +1 for posting a well articulated question alongside with the relevant code. To everyone else, before chastising the OP please consider that it's not always easy, especially for a self declared beginner, to find the right keywords to lookup even an "*obvious*" answer. For example, SO's own logic, supposedly well seasoned in C++, still doesn't appear to connect `double dash before a variable` to `prefix decrement operator` judging by what's listed under the `related` column for this question - even after multiple answers have been posted.

Comment: +1 for a valid question that may be difficult to search for.  This may not be so obvious for beginners... the first hit on Bing for "double dash c++" is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035368/double-dash-before-a-variable-in-c :). (ofc why use Bing?...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its the [prefix decrement operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec). It subtracts 1 from the variable and stores the result back in the variable. As an expression, it has the value of the result after the decrement. There's also a postfix decrement operator that behaves identically except the value of the expression is the variable value before the decrement.

(That's because `num_strings` is an `int`. Of course, like most operators in C++, if the variable is a class, it can define its own semantics for the prefix `--` operator, so all bets are off as to what it does.)

Answer (score 5):

**--** it is the prefix decrement operator and it means that you do absent one from the value.

```
--num_strings;
```

it's exactly the same like:

```
num_strings=num string -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `--` is C++'s decrement operator (decreases the value of it's operand by one). Inside the constructor, memory is allocated off the heap (free store) to hold an array of `char strings` and `num_strings` is incremented by one just to keep track of the number of those arrays of char strings floating around at any given time. In the destructor, the memory that was allocated to that char array is returned back to the free store using the `delete[]` operator, but to make sure that `num_strings` is still correct, it has to be decreased by one and that is exactly what the `--` operator is doing inside the destructor.